# How to check if a specific index in a boolean array is true is C#

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean, boolean-expression

I have to create a simplistic windows form application that assigns customers to seats in either First Class 1-5 or Economy Class 6-10. I have to use a single dimension boolean array. I cant figure out how to check to see if a specific index has been made *True*. If the the array is true it either moves on or creates a messagebox. I just need help on how to check if its true.

```
for (int i = 5; i < 9; i++)<br>
{
   assignedSeat[i] = true;
   if (assignedSeat[9] == true)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("You chose Economy Class", "Economy Class", 
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK);
   }
   else
   {
       DialogResult g = MessageBox.Show("Unfortunately, Economy class is full. Next flight in 3 hours",  
              "Oh No", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
       if (g == DialogResult.OK)
       {
            TxtClassChoice.Clear();
       }
       else
       {
            Close();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to check for `assignedSeat[9]` only after the for loop completed, or?

Comment: How are you getting the seat number ? you would usually just do something like this (no loop needed)   `if (assignedSeat[seatNumber-1]) { SomeSmething}` remembering arrays are 0 based

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion here is the for loop.

```
for (int i = 5; i < 9; i++)
```

9 - 5 = 4.

You're only checking 4 seats here.  Seats 6 through 9.

`if (assignedSeat[9] == true)` will always be false.  That's because of the `i < 9` condition.

Knowing that, the line `assignedSeat[i] = true;` will never run `assignedSeat[9] = true;`.

The default value for a boolean is false.

If you want to check seats 6 through 10 change `i < 9` to `i < 10`:

```
for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
```

> I cant figure out how to check to see if a specific index has been
> made True.

`if (assignedSeat[9] == true)` is perfectly fine.  It can be shortened to `if (assignedSeat[9])` but that's just preference.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two errors in your code. First you need to loop over all seats to check one by one if they are free or not. This means looping from 5 to 9 included (index 5 is for seat 6 because arrays are zero based). The second error is the assignement to true for each seat. This of course should be done only one time when you find a free seat not for every loop.

However after fixing these errors there is something more that you can do. Try to separate the logic to check for free seats from the logic that displays the messages.

```
// Cycle from 5 to 9 (seats 6-10)
int seatNum = 5;
while(seatNum < 10)
{
    // If the seat is free stop the cycle
    if(!assignedSeat[seatNum])
        break;

    seatNum++;
}

// If we exit the loop after reaching the last seat then we don't have free seats
if(i == 10)
    MessageBox.Show("Unfortunately, Economy class is full.....");
else
{
    assignedSeat[seatNum] = true;
    MessageBox("You chose Economy Class, assigned seat is " + seatNum+1);
}
```